# statistics in python program wont output what i expect

Tags: python

I am trying to do a program for a class and it is supposed to take multiple values and output user selected statistic data. however all it does is asks for another selection.

Here is the code I have:

```
import statistics

values=[12,22,56,44,33,25,18,5,33,66]

print('#####################################################')

print('Choose from the MENU to perform given task ')

print('1- Calculate the mean value for the List')

print('2- Calculate the median value for the List')

print('3- Calculate the mode value for the List')

print('4- Calculate the Range value for the List')

print('5- Sort the values in ascending order in the List')

print('6- Calculate the standard deviation for the List')

print('-1 To EXIT')

print('#####################################################')

for i in range(7):
    user_in=int(input('What is your choice? '))
        if user_in == -1:
        break
else:
    while user_in != -1:
        if user_in == 1:
            mean_val=statistics.mean(values)
            print(f'Mean is {mean_val:.2f}')
            break
        elif user_in == 2:
            median_val=statistics.median(values)
            print(f'Median is {median_val:.2f}')
            break
        elif user_in == 3:
            mode_val=statistics.mode(values)
            print(f'Mode is {mode_val:.2f}')
            break
        elif user_in == 4:
            range_val=max(values)-min(values)
            print(f'Range is {range_val}')
            break
        elif user_in == 5:
            sort_val=sorted(values)
            print(f'Sorted {sort_val}')
            break
        elif user_in == 6:
            sd_dev=statistics.stdev(values)
            print(f'Standard Deviation {sd_dev:.2f}')
            break
        else:
            print('Invalid Entry')
            break
print('EXIT is selected')
```

I was expecting some sort of answer to be output but all that outputs is the program asking for selection.

Comment: Well, you *did* tell it to ask for input 7 times...

Comment: What is `for i in range(7)` supposed to do?

Comment: the professor put it in his code and i copied part of his code. how do i fix it so it only asks for more input after it outputs the answer

Comment: I am pretty new to python if there is a way to fix it i would like to know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bro you have an indentation mistake. Your if/else need to have the same indentation. then it works. else be careful or u burn your hand! Look below the code:

```
import statistics

values=[12,22,56,44,33,25,18,5,33,66]

print('#####################################################')

print('Choose from the MENU to perform given task ')

print('1- Calculate the mean value for the List')

print('2- Calculate the median value for the List')

print('3- Calculate the mode value for the List')

print('4- Calculate the Range value for the List')

print('5- Sort the values in ascending order in the List')

print('6- Calculate the standard deviation for the List')

print('-1 To EXIT')

print('#####################################################')

for i in range(7):
    user_in=int(input('What is your choice? '))
    if user_in == -1:
        break
    else:
        while user_in != -1:
            if user_in == 1:
                mean_val=statistics.mean(values)
                print(f'Mean is {mean_val:.2f}')
                break
            elif user_in == 2:
                median_val=statistics.median(values)
                print(f'Median is {median_val:.2f}')
                break
            elif user_in == 3:
                mode_val=statistics.mode(values)
                print(f'Mode is {mode_val:.2f}')
                break
            elif user_in == 4:
                range_val=max(values)-min(values)
                print(f'Range is {range_val}')
                break
            elif user_in == 5:
                sort_val=sorted(values)
                print(f'Sorted {sort_val}')
                break
            elif user_in == 6:
                sd_dev=statistics.stdev(values)
                print(f'Standard Deviation {sd_dev:.2f}')
                break
            else:
                print('Invalid Entry')
                break
print('EXIT is selected')
```